# C: how to read many strings from stdin

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, eof

I need to read many strings with a variable length from stdin up to EOF.
The strings are made of consecutive chars, not separated by blanks and there is not a maximum length for the strings.

Using:

```
char st[101];
while(scanf("%100s",st) != EOF){ //divide the input into parts of 100 chars
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(st);i++){
        printf("%c",st[i]);
    }
}
```

I can not tell if the current string is part of a previous one or a new one because it is printed all in a single line (and I've no idea where to print "\n").

*Sample input*:

```
aaaaaaaaa[...]aaaaa

bbbbbbbbb[...]bbbbb
```

*output*:

```
aaaa[...]aabbbbbb[...]bbbb
```

Any solution?

P.S. Using `getchar()` I'm not able to handle the EOF.

Comment: How are the strings separated?

Comment: What do you mean, you "can't handle the EOF"? Why not?

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: There's a string per line

Comment: Then just use `getline()`: https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline

Comment: OK, and what do you want to do with those strings?

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. You wrote " it is printed all in a single line" then in a comment you wrote "There's a string per line"

Comment: After getting the whole string, I have to modify it through other functions (I put printf just to figure out what the output was)

Comment: If there is a string per line & without white spaces and there is not a maximum length then you can use `getline()`, for e.g `char *st = NULL; while(getline(&st,&size,stdin)!=EOF) {   printf("%s",st); }`

Comment: @nicomp in the input there is a string per line, but I need to get 
one line at a time and work on it, then move on to the next; instead using the code I reported I can only print the entire input in output on a single line

Comment: @achal but there's not a size

Comment: you can define it right @Mr.WhiteBear ? for e.g `size_t size = 0;` Before that please read the man page of `getline()` to know how it works.

Comment: @achal getline() worked very well. I've just another problem: before the first string, in the input there's a word I don't need to store (for e.g "run"), If i scanf() that word and then I start getline() the strings, on the output I get a blank line, but I don't print it.

Comment: But I'm not sure I can use getline(), because I can only use C standard library (libc)

Comment: I can't figure out if getline is in the C standard library. If it is I can use it.

Comment: This feels like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you handle `EOF` with `getchar`:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
}
```

This code will replicate its input on stdout.

If you want to deal with whole lines at a time, the easiest way is to use `getline` if you have it (it's POSIX, not standard C):

```
char *line = NULL;
size_t size = 0;

ssize_t nread;
while ((nread = getline(&line, &size, stdin)) != -1) {
    // nread characters were read
    do_stuff_with(line);
}
free(line);
```

If you don't have `getline`, you get to write your own (using `getchar` and `realloc`).

Comment: I can only use C standard library (libc)

Comment: @Mr.WhiteBear Then the last sentence of my answer applies (but note that `getline` is in libc, which contains much more than the C standard library and much less (`sqrt` and friends are usually in libm, not libc)).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for your help

Comment: I've just know I can't use getline(). How can I handle my problem using fgets()?